# Azure functions remote build with CI (github actions)

Tags: azure-functions, puppeteer, github-actions

I'm currently developing an Azure Function that needs to be built remotely, as it uses an embedded installation of Chromium to be used by puppeteer. I would like to use github actions to facilitate deployment, but don't know if this is reliable/possible.

I initially set it up with a Github Action for continuous deployment, but now with a preliminary version I'm having an error about Puppeteer not finding the required installation of Chromium. I think it might be due to the action's configuration, but I can't find if remote building from github actions is possible.
My question is: has this been done? Is it possible or should I go back to manual deployment?

Comment: You probably need to change the config directory to make sure Puppeteer looks up the binary at the same location where it gets installed: https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration#changing-the-default-cache-directory

Comment: Thanks! setting up puppeteer's installation directory inside my project with .puppeteerrc solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Caveat: This answer assumes Azure Javascript Functions v3, Azure/functions-action@v1, and Puppeteer v20. All of which are the current versions as of this posting. Newer versions of any of those packages could break these steps.*

1.) Add a file to the root of your project as referenced here: https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration#changing-the-default-cache-directory

```
// .puppeteerrc.cjs
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  cacheDirectory: path.join(__dirname, ".cache", "puppeteer"),
};
```

2.) Enable `scm-do-build-during-deployment` and `enable-oryx-build` in your actions file to force a remote build as referenced here: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-functions-action#github-action-parameters

```
- name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        with:
          ...
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
```

These two steps combined will ensure that Azure properly deploys the chromium binary located in the cache directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems like a perfectly clean solution. Unfortunately, I ended up moving away from using azure functions in favor of a K8s CronJob, because the functions ended up being pretty unstable in performance and resource availability for such a heavy task as running a browser. For anyone going down this path, I'd recommend a heavier hosting than what Azure functions has to offer, or otherwise go for one of the bigger plans